# What is the efficient way to code Successive Over-relaxation (SOR) method in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have written a SOR method (SOR is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation) method) code using C-style procedural loops.

However, I think there might be (much) better ways to achieve the same end in Mma avoiding these loops.

So my question is: Is that feasible to code SOR method using functions like `Nest`, `Fold` that could be substantially more efficient?

For example, the following is a simple set of multiline equations with tridiagonal matrix.(my original equations will have an larger coefficient matrix, like 100*100 tridiagonal sparse array.)

[image]

1. Let `listnew` be the list that stores the unknown $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ after each time of iteration.
2. And `listold` correspondingly stores the unknowns before each time of iteration.
3. `b` stores right-hand side of the equation above.
4. `k` indicates the times of iteration.
5. `i` is the index of $x_i$.
6. `ϵ` is the pre-defined maximum error.
7. `error` indicates the maximum difference between `listnew` and `listold` after each iteration.
8. `ω` is the so-called relaxation factor.

Then, my (dumb) code using `For` loop would be:

```
ϵ = 0.1;
ω = 1.5;
b = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
listnew = listold = Table[0, {i, 5}];
error = ϵ + 1;
For[k = 0, error > ϵ, k++,
    listnew[[1]] = listold[[1]] - ω (b[[1]] + 4 listold[[1]] - listold[[2]])/4;
    For[i = 2, i < 5, i++, 
        listnew[[i]] = listold[[i]] - 
                       ω (b[[i]] + 4 listold[[i]] - listnew[[i - 1]] - listold[[i + 1]])/4];
    listnew[[5]] = listold[[5]] - ω (b[[5]] + 4 listold[[5]] - listnew[[4]])/4;
    error = Max[Abs[listnew - listold]]; listold = listnew;]
```

I'm sorry if it looks so dumb...

Comment: Can you please explain what's SOR method and add your code?

Comment: Can you share your implementation of SOR using the loop method in Mathematica? (may be with sample input, how it is called, and sample output?) SOR is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation

Comment: I have coded this before as an exercise but you are better off using the built in solvers in Mma

Comment: My response to [this query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292305/tunkrank-in-mathematica) has a simple implementation of the Jacobi method. It might be possible to modify that to get SOR.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. I have revised my question and added some (if too dumb) code. Hope you can have a look at it and share what you think about it. :-)

Comment: @Nasser And thank you too. I have added my simplified code to the question. Hope you can have a look at it and share what you think about it. :-)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Yes, I have realized this. Can you suggest some possible choices of efficient method and/or function to be used? My primitive idea is: Manually construct a sparse array, then apply `LinearSolve` to it. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for your kindness help. I will think about possible revision on it. :-)

Comment: Sorry for my delayed improvement to the question. My computer suffered misery recently and have just recovered.

Comment: You are using `for` loop there over `k`, but `k` is not used anywhere in the body. You can replace `For[k = 0, error > \[Epsilon], k++,` by just `While[error > \[Epsilon],`

Comment: If you just want to solve the equations rather than practicing programming SOR method, just use `LinearSolve`, your self-made solver will probably never have a chance to beat it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You asking for "efficient" implementation. SOR is an iterative process. One does a step, checks if converged or not, and if not, repeat the step. I found M to be very fast using plain old `Do`. I do not see the point of replacing a well understand algorithm expressed naturally using `Do[ f[i,....], {i,1,n}]`, by something like `f[#,...] &/@ Range[n]` or other variations, just for the sake of syntax change.

But the reason I am writing is not this. I just thought your iterative implementation was not clear so will post implementation of SOR based on direct implementation of the formula I am familiar with, as seen in this [Mathematical association of America page](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/loci/joma/iterative-methods-for-solving-iaxi-ibi-the-sor-method)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above solves `A x = b` using SOR. So $a_{ii}$ is the diagonal entry of $A$ and $k+1$ is the new solution and $k$ is the old solution. Guess starts with the zero solution.

The loop above is implemented using `Do` and those inner summations are implemented using the `Sum` command. The check for convergence uses relative error check. For additional speed, one can try to `Compile` this. As others said, SOR is not used in practice to solve real problem. It is only for academic interest as there are faster iterative methods these days, and if you have lots of RAM, you can just use a direct solver. `LinearSolve` in Mathematica.

Here is an implementation of the above equation. You can change omega and for fixed tolerance, see the effect on how many iterations are needed to converge.

[image]

```
Manipulate[tick;
 Module[{keepRunning = True, i, j, xOld = Table[0, {5}], n = 5}, 
  While[keepRunning, 
   Do[x[[i]] = xOld[[i]] + w/mat[[i, i]] (b[[i]] - 
    Sum[mat[[i, j]] x[[j]], {j, 1, i - 1}] - Sum[mat[[i, j]] xOld[[j]], {j, i, n}])
    , {i, 1, n}
    ];
   If[Norm[x - xOld]/Norm[x] < e,
    keepRunning = False,
    xOld = x;
    k++
    ]
   ]
  ];

 Grid[{
   {Row[{"Iteration needed to converge ", k}], SpanFromLeft},
   {TableForm[{x, direct}, TableHeadings -> {{"SOR", "direct"}, 
     {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"}}], SpanFromLeft}},
  Spacings -> {1, 1}, Frame -> All], 

 Grid[{{Button["RUN", k = 0; x = Table[0, {5}]; tick = Not[tick]]}}],

 {{w, 1.5, "w"}, 1.1, 1.9, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},(*sor omega*)
 {{e, 0.0001, "error tolerance"}, 0.000000001, 0.001, 0.000000001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 {{x, Table[0, {5}]}, None}, 
 {{k, 0}, None}, 
 {{tick, False}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick},

 Initialization :> (SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 16];
   mat = {{-4, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, -4, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, -4, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, -4, 1}, 
   {0, 0, 0, 1, -4}};
   b = Table[1, {5}];
   direct = N@LinearSolve[mat, b]
   )
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Your answer clarified some of my confusions. And I found many to learn from your code. Based on my limited numerical analysis knowledge, I really don't know any modern (and more efficient) solver to implement in solving large matrix. I will for sure learn some more practical methods in the future. :-)

Answer (score 7):

[Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) has given a good answer, here's just some complements.

First, a literal translation for the first formula provided in [the wikipedia of SOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation):

```
methodSOR1[a_, b_, ω_, ϕ_, ϵ_] := 
 Module[{d, l, u, coe1, coe2, coe3}, {d, l, u} = 
   N@{DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal@#, LowerTriangularize[#, -1], UpperTriangularize[#, 1]} &@a; 
  coe1 = Inverse[d + ω l]; coe2 = ω b; coe3 = (ω u + (ω - 1) d); 
  FixedPoint[coe1.(coe2 - coe3.#) &, ϕ, SameTest -> (Max@Abs[#1 - #2] < ϵ &)]]
```

Then, the implementation of the second formula (compiled version), notice the `Module` inside the code is necessary for the speed up because it localizes intermediate variables i.e. `ϕ`, `ϕold`, `n` in the function:

```
methodSOR2 = 
  Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}, {b, _Real, 1}, {ϕ0, _Real, 1}, {ω, _Real}, {ϵ, _Real}}, 
   Module[{ϕ = ϕ0, ϕold = ϕ0 + 1, n = Length@ϕ0}, 
    While[Max@Abs[ϕold - ϕ] > ϵ, ϕold = ϕ; 
     Do[ϕ[[i]] = (1 - ω) ϕ[[i]] + 
        ω/a[[i, i]] (b[[i]] - Sum[a[[i, j]] ϕ[[j]], {j, i - 1}] - 
           Sum[a[[i, j]] ϕ[[j]], {j, i + 1, n}]), {i, n}]]; ϕ]];
```

Finally, since you have optimize the formula for your specific problem, I'd like to give an example of compiling your original code with minimal effort:

```
specificSOR = 
  With[{end = 5000}, 
   With[{ϵ = 0.1, ω = 1.5, b = ConstantArray[1., {end}], list = ConstantArray[0., {end}]},
    Compile[{}, 
     Module[{listold = list, listnew = list, error = ϵ + 1, k, i},
      For[k = 0, error > ϵ, k++, 
       listnew[[1]] = listold[[1]] - ω (b[[1]] + 4 listold[[1]] - listold[[2]])/4;
       For[i = 2, i < end, i++, 
        listnew[[i]] = listold[[i]] - 
                       ω (b[[i]] + 4 listold[[i]] - listnew[[i - 1]] - listold[[i + 1]])/4];
       listnew[[end]] = listold[[end]] - 
                        ω (b[[end]] + 4 listold[[end]] - listnew[[end - 1]])/4;
       error = Max[Abs[listnew - listold]]; listold = listnew]; 
      listnew]]]];
```

Of course using `Do` and `While` instead of `For` will make the code look better.

Finally it bears repeating that if you're not practicing programming SOR, just use `LinearSolve` for your equations.